# LDAP Java print debug output

Tags: java, debugging, active-directory, ldap, jndi

When one configure application settings it always useful to show debug/output of the process.
E.g. `javax.mail.Session` has `debug` and `debugOutput`. Is it something similar in parameters/API for `InitialDirContext`/`InitialLdapContext`/`LdapCtxFactory` Java classes?

My goal is to give a user debug info if something is going wrong with LDAP connection.

P.S. Java code is trivial:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  domainController);
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); 
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, login);
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    //initializing active directory LDAP connection
    InitialDirContext dirContext = null;
    try {
        dirContext = new InitialDirContext(properties);
        System.out.println("OK!");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        //ignore auth. exception
        System.out.println("Failed!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(dirContext != null)
            try {
                dirContext.close();
            } catch (NamingException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug` system property to `all` and it should provide the information that you need.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/config.html